# CSS Tailwind How to target first row of css grid

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

In my `vue`-app I'm doing this loop

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-14">
   <article-card v-for="(article, index) in articles" :key="index" :content="article" />
</div>
```

So far so good, but I want to display **the first row** of the `css-grid` differently -> e.g. something like `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1.5fr;` - just to make them more visible

How can I do that? Can someone help me out? I'm using `tailwindcss`, so maybe that could help?

Answer (score 0):

Style an element when it is the first-child using the **"first"** modifiers:

In your code use condition for the first index (I assume it 1) and use the style, I think you know the condition implementation I just mention the style usage-

```
 <article-card  first:your-style />
```

For more see the official tailwind CSS documentation. [First, last, odd, and even](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first-last-odd-and-even)

Also a code example I get from Tailwind CSS, that might help you.

```
<ul role="list" class="p-6 divide-y divide-slate-200">
   {#each people as person}
      <!-- Remove top/bottom padding when first/last child -->
      <li class="flex py-4 first:pt-0 last:pb-0">
         <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="{person.imageUrl}" alt="" />
         <div class="ml-3 overflow-hidden">
            <p class="text-sm font-medium text-slate-900">{person.name}</p>
            <p class="text-sm text-slate-500 truncate">{person.email}</p>
         </div>
      </li>
   {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tailwind v3 then you can just use arbitrary values feature, for example like that:

```
<div class="grid-cols-[200px_minmax(900px,_1fr)_100px]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

So just wrap values in square brackets `[...]` and use `_` instead of spaces.

[More info in the docs as always](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#arbitrary-values)